# Flutter just_audio custom mp3 stream source audio is choppy

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, audio-streaming, just-audio

I am using just_audio to stream mp3 from the response without waiting till the whole music data is obtained. But the audio played is totally choppy.

This the custom audio source class -

```
// Feed your own stream of bytes into the player
class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final List<int> bytes;
  MyCustomSource(this.bytes);
  
  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    start ??= 0;
    end ??= bytes.length;
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: bytes.length,
      contentLength: end - start,
      offset: start,
      stream: Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    );
  }
}

await player.setAudioSource(MyCustomSource());
player.play();
```

My code for sending a post request and then listening on the streamedResponse is as follows:

```
final request = http.Request(
                  'POST',
                  Uri.parse(
                      "URL"));
              request.bodyFields = {'xyz': 'abc'};
              _streamedResponse = await request.send();
              _streamedResponse?.stream.listen((data) async {
                log(data.toString());
                await japlayer.setAudioSource(MyCustomSource(data), preload: false);
                await japlayer.play();
              }).onDone(() async {
                await japlayer.stop();
              });
```

Even though it plays the audio, it just spells the first two characters of every word and the reason for this is as and when we receive data in the stream, I am creating a new audio source. Need help in streaming the audio without any issue.

Comment: Did you found any solution?